# xcode preprocessor macros LLVM 4.2

Tags: xcode, preprocessor, llvm

I am trying to set DEBUG_MODE macro for DLOG to work only debug mode but it is not working...

What I tried so far: http://developer.sinnerschrader-mobile.com/llvm-preprocessor-macros-xcode/275/

and naming one more flag as DEBUG_MODE, playing combinations with or without $(inherited) value.

I am all confused, what is green highlighted part stands for? and why is some parts seen empty but when clicked values are seen in it?

How should I configure my macros so that I can really access them for:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#   define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#   define DLog(...) do { } while (0)
#endif
```

[image]

EDIT:

This is become really wicked! I have set all values to DEBUG=0 in release mode. And changed

```
#if DEBUG
#   define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#   define DLog(...) do { } while (0)
#endif
```

still seeing all logs in release...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Preprocessor macro settings (Debug being `DEBUG=1` and Release being `DEBUG=0`) will cause the first definition of the `DLog()` macro to be used given you have used `#ifdef` (if defined) to provide different implementations. This is because the macro will be *defined* if you define it at all, **regardless of what you define it to**.

What you need to do is, either:

- Remove `DEBUG=0` from your Release profile.
- Use `#if DEBUG` instead of `#ifdef DEBUG`.

Comment: @tugce Your code now looks OK to me; I would have expected that to work.  Are you saying that `DLog()` produces output in Release mode?

Comment: yes, unfortunately in release mode DLog() still produces output

Comment: @tugce Have to ensured that you have cleaned and rebuilt your entire project?

Comment: wow, this is all my wrong assumption about release and debug modes. created new scheme for release and worked like a charm. thanks for the help